# X509 HttpServletRequest getAttribute is null

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, x509certificate

I'm making an spring boot aplication which has to verify the client certificate and then extract certain data from it. To verify it I send the client certificate to OcspResponder to verify it.
The problem is when i try to cacth the certificate from the HttpServeletRequest it returns null.

I'm using Springboot and my application.properties look like this:

```
server.port=8443

server.ssl.key-store-type=JKS
server.ssl.key-store=classpath:keystore.jks
server.ssl.key-store-password=changeit

server.ssl.trust-store-type=JKS
server.ssl.trust-store=classpath:truststore.jks
server.ssl.trust-store-password=changeit

server.ssl.client-auth=need
security.require-ssl=true
```

The code i'm using to get the certificate is this:

```
@Controller
    public class CertController {

    @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('ROLE_USER')")
    @RequestMapping(value = "/user", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String verifyCert(HttpServletRequest request) {

        X509Certificate[] certs =          (X509Certificate[])request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.request.X509Certificate");

        if (certs != null && certs.length > 0) {
            System.out.println("certs is not null");
            return certs[0].toString();
        }else
            return "Error";
    }
}
```

And to extract data from it I use:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class X509AuthenticationServer {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeHttpRequests()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and().x509()
                .subjectPrincipalRegex("CN=(.*?)(?:,|$)")
                .userDetailsService(userDetailsService());
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        return new UserDetailsService() {
            @Override
            public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
                System.out.println("Subject: " + username);
                return new User(username, "",
                        AuthorityUtils.commaSeparatedStringToAuthorityList("ROLE_USER"));
            }
        };
    }

}
```

The thing is that I'm able to extract the username of the certificate but I'm getting null on the HttpServletRequest.

Any idea on how to solve it?

Comment: Which Spring Boot version?

Comment: Spring boot version is 3.1.1 @M.Deinum

Comment: Then you have the wrong attribute name. Use `jakarta.servlet.request.X509Certificate` instead.

Answer (score 0):

As M. Deinum said in comments, don't forget to change

```
javax.servlet.request.X509Certificate
```

to

```
jakarta.servlet.request.X509Certificate
```

with Spring Boot 3.X (and Java 17).

Thanks to him for the anwer, I post it here to view it better...